# How to display list object to a view in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model

I'm having a hard time displaying the values from a list object model to the view.

I've tried to display it using this code

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC.Models.RootObject>

@foreach (var item in @Model)
{
    <li>@item.records</li>
}
```

But it shows an error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MVC.Models.RootObject', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MVC.Models.RootObject]'.

Here is my controller that I used to pass data from model to view

```
           var transno = "ST-100420190001";

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://myurl.com/" + transno),
                Headers = {
                { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" },
                { HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/json"},
                { "client-id", "client_id"},
                { "client-secret","client_secret"},
                { "partner-id","partner_id"},
                { "X-Version", "1" }
            }
            };

            var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
            RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(await 
            response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            return View(obj);
```

The RootObject model looks like this

```
public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Record> records { get; set; }
        public int totalRecords { get; set; }
    }
```

Then the Record model looks like this

```
 public class Record
    {
        public string transferId { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
        public string dateUpdated { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string senderTransferId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the `@model` line in your view file? The error suggests it is `IEnumerable<RootObject>` and yet you are passing a single `RootObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Okay let's have a look at the error message**

Your view is expecting `IEnumerable` of `RootObject`, but you're just passing in a single RootObject.

`` The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MVC.Models.RootObject', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MVC.Models.RootObject]'. ``

I'm not sure what your API is replying with, but you may need to `DeserializeObject` to an `IEnumerable` of `RootObject` instead of a single object. have you tried debugging these lines?

```cs
var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

return View(obj);
```

**If this is not the case and you're looking to make multiple API calls to build a list at a later date**

Something like this should work, but I'd recommend following the above as it seems like more what you're looking for, judging by the razor you posted.

```cs
var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(await 
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

IEnumerable<RootObject> list = new List<RootObject>(){ obj };

return View(list);
```

Comment: What my api is returning is a list of 'record' object like what in my 'record' model shows. Your second suggestion works for me but is it okay to make multiple api calls to build a list? Doesn't it slows down the page?

Comment: @ikey it will slow down the page. You'll need to call an endpoint that returns a list of `record` object then `DeserializeObject` an `IEnumerable<RootObject>`

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, you want to change the `@model` line and potentially flesh out the loop as follows.

```
@model MVC.Models.RootObject

@foreach (var item in @Model.records)
{
    <li>@item.transferId</li>
    <li>@item.type</li>
    // etc
}
```

Comment: I have encountered this error after I used your code suggestion. 'IEnumerable<RootObject>' does not contain a definition for 'records' and no extension method 'records' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<RootObject>' could be found

Comment: @ikey That is because you have not gave `records` any value, therefore it is null

Comment: But after i debug the program I see that a value is passed to `records`. Maybe this code is the problem? `IEnumerable<MVC.Models.RootObject>`

Comment: @ikey This does not sound like you have changed the `foreach` correctly. Have you editted it to loop through the `records` instead of the model? / changed the view model from a list to a single model

Comment: I've added the `@model` line in my answer, it should just be the `RootObject` not a collection of them.